# Imprimir os dados dum vetor numa struct

Tags: c, array, struct

Quero fazer um sistema de cadastro de datas de aniversário. A dúvida final é: como imprimo os aniversário: 1/12/1990, 12/2/1977, 13/09/1999 e 19/04/1987. Seriam os exemplos da impressão das datas, mas me aparecem vários números que não tem nada a ver. Segue o código.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int ano;
} data;

int main()
{
    data data_aniversario[4];
    int i=0;

    while (i<4)
    {
        printf("Preencha sua data de nascimento\n\n");
        printf("Digite o dia: ");
        scanf("%d", &data_aniversario[i].dia);
        printf("\n\nDigite o mes: ");
        scanf("%d", &data_aniversario[i].mes);
        printf("\n\nDigite o ano: ");
        scanf("%d", &data_aniversario[i].ano);
    }

    printf("\n\nA data do seu aniversário é: \n");
    printf("%d/%d/%d\n", data_aniversario.dia, data_aniversario.mes, data_aniversario.ano);
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Há dois problemas no seu código:

- Falta você incrementar a variável que controla o *loop* onde pede os dados. Você está guardando as quatro datas no mesmo local e acho que não é o que você quer.
- Quando você imprime as datas de nascimento não está usando um *loop*. Você está tentando imprimir o *array* e não os elementos dele. Não é possível imprimir o *array* como um todo, o *array* é apenas um endereço de memória, daí aparecem números estranhos. No caso específico você não pode nem imprimir os elementos mas sim os membros desses elementos, mas isto estava certo no seu código, faltava só indexar o *array* da mesma forma que você fez corretamente quando estava lendo os dados.

Além disto o nome da variável, apesar de não causar problemas no código, passa ideia errada do que ela guarda.

Veja:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int ano;
} data;

int main() {
    data data_aniversario[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("Preencha sua data de nascimento\n\n");
        printf("Digite o dia: ");
        scanf("%d", &data_aniversario[i].dia);
        printf("\n\nDigite o mes: ");
        scanf("%d", &data_aniversario[i].mes);
        printf("\n\nDigite o ano: ");
        scanf("%d", &data_aniversario[i].ano);
    }
    for (int i = 0;i < 4;i++) {
        printf("\n\nA data do seu aniversário é: \n");
        printf("%d/%d/%d\n", data_aniversario[i].dia, data_aniversario[i].mes, data_aniversario[i].ano);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/RIk0tL). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/juasgnze-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/FillData.c).

Answer (score 2):

Quando você imprime as datas, você está fazendo:

```
printf("%d/%d/%d\n", data_aniversario.dia, data_aniversario.mes, data_aniversario.ano);
```

E deve ser `data_aniversario[0].dia`, variando de 0 até 3 para imprimir todas as datas.

---

Obs: está faltando também um i++ para parar o `while`. Ou você pode utilizar um `for`.

```
while (i<4)
{
     // seu código
     i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`data_aniversario` é um *array* com 4 elementos `data`.
Você faz o *input* de 4 datas e guarda nesse array.
Para imprimir você terá de utilizar um *loop* que percorra todos os elementos de `data_aniversario`.

Qualquer coisa do género:

```
for(i = 0; i < 4;i++)
{
    printf("\n\nA data do seu aniversário é: \n");
    printf("%d/%d/%d\n", data_aniversario[i].dia, data_aniversario[i].mes, data_aniversario[i].ano);
}
```